# LinkedIn and Facebook like buttons change images and title?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api, meta

I am using the LinkedIn like button and the Facebook Like button.

On the LinkedIn when I click like, it works property, but I was wondering how I would change the name of the title on the pop dialog that comes up?.

For the Facebook Like button, how would I change the image thumbnail in the pop dialog box?.

Well I got the image thumbnail to work using

```
 <meta property="og:image"
```

How ever I still have not been able to change the title for LinkedIn

I tried:

```
<meta property="og:title"
<meta property="og:site_name"
```

and none of those worked....is there a debugging site for LinkedIn, like Facebook does.

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I know, it is not og:site_name, but og:title. The code below works perfectly for me so I am enclosing it (remember to change the content). Hopefully it'll fix your problem.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" /> 
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
        <meta property="og:title" content="My cool website" /> 
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="ADMINS_ID"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/images/mylogo.png" />
```